# creating nested json with gson in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to create a nested json object to send to a webapplication.

Currenty I have just a simple request, it's working fine. But now I need to add a nested Json object with several levels.

Currenty we are using gson to generate our json object.

Heres the current code in java

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

FinalizeRequestData finalizeData = new FinalizeRequestData();
       finalizeData.setLoanNumber(loanNumber);
       finalizeData.setCustomerAcceptedLoan(customerResponse);

String s = gson.toJson(finalizeData);

System.out.println("s = " + s);
```

Above code works as it should and prints

```
s = {"loanNumber":LOANNUMBER,"customerAcceptedLoan":true}
```

The finalizeData is a simple class with setter och getter.

Now I need to add more objects. I'm stuck and don't know how to do it. I guess I need a Kyc class and some kind of map or list? I'm a noob. But I want to use gson.toJson

This is how it should look like.

```
{
   "LoanNumber": "nnnnnn",

    "CustomerAcceptedLoan": true,

    "Kyc": [{

        "Questions": {
            "Date": "2016-01-28T15:40:19.185375+01:00",
            "Items": [

             {
                "QuestionText": "Question 1 Text?",
                "AnswerText": "Answer 1 text"
            },

            {
                "QuestionText": "Question 2 Text?",
                "AnswerText": "Answer 2 text"
            },

            {
                "QuestionText": "Question 3 Text?",
                "AnswerText": "Answer 3 text"
            },

            {
                "QuestionText": "Question 4 Text",
                "AnswerText": "Answer 4 Text"
            },


            ]
        },

        "IsPep": false,
        "CivicNumber": "nnnn"

    }]
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help! Hope I can contribute in some other question on the board.

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: Just a few examples with gson I've found. And tried to map out how I should write this with no success

Comment: start by building the object you want to serialize, show it  to us + whatever you tried and haven't succeed

Comment: Right now I have just created it as a static string where I have just added the values which i'm getting from a class (getter/setter class). 

Quick fix that works. Will develope it better later.

Comment: I don't understand. You show the expcted output without having an input? How can anyone answer to this?

Comment: The inputs comes from a class. But instead of generating the json object I just print it out and write the values from the class in the right places

Comment: see my comment 23 days ago ^